# not sure why these 2 pieces of R code give different results. Using function() and for()

Tags: function, for-loop

```
testing <- c(20,40,60,80)
w1u50 = 0
w1o50 = 0
test_my_function <- function(y){
for(x in y){
  if(x < 50){
    w1u50 <- w1u50 +1
  }else{
  w1o50 <- w1o50 +1
  }
}
}
test_my_function(testing)
w1u50
w1o50
```

## I'm trying to get w1u50 and w1o50 to return results of 2 each as they do in the below script. Instead they're returning 0 counts in the above script.

```
testing <- c(20,40,60,80)
w1u50 = 0
w1o50 = 0

for(x in testing){
  if(x < 50){
    w1u50 <- w1u50 +1
  }else{
  w1o50 <- w1o50 +1
  }
}

w1u50
w1o50
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is now. Variables inside functions are local to that function. To get round this problem when creating the variables inside the function i need to use <<- instead of <-.